# Change BorderBrush when button IsPressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I'm creating a WPF application for a touchscreen.
There should be a button on the screen with an Icon (image).
The code below shows how the button should look like.

So far so good..

What I would like to achieve is that when you press the button, the first BorderBrush color should change from “#0070b8” to “#00395c” and the second BorderBrush color should change from “#e3e3e3” to “#727272”.

Could someone please help me how to achieve this?

```
<Button Width="64" Height="64" Grid.Row="1" Margin="1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Source="Resources\Home_Icon_2.bmp" Width="54" Height="54"></Image>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="button" Width="64">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" BorderBrush="#0070b8" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=CornerRadius}">
                                        <Border.Effect>
                                            <BlurEffect Radius="1" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                                        </Border.Effect>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="#e3e3e3" Opacity="0.5" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=CornerRadius}">
                                        <Border.Effect>
                                            <BlurEffect Radius="1" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                                        </Border.Effect>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextBlock.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="#e3e3e3" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#c6c3c6" />
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one solution.  Note that we've assigned our brushes to separate resources so that we don't have magic numbers in our style.  This is ideal for when you need to use the same colour scheme across multiple controls, and saves a lot of time when you want to change said colour scheme.

```
    <Style x:Key="AdtakrButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="ButtonBorder" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="{DynamicResource AdtakrButtonBorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AdtakrBlack}" Background="{DynamicResource AdtakrWhite}" Margin="{DynamicResource ButtonMargin}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,6,0" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrGrey2}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrGrey2}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrGrey1}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrGrey2}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrGrey2}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrLightBlue}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrLightBlue}" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource AdtakrDefFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="90"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
```

If you need to have it change between more than 1 colour, then your best bet is to have a command on your databound VM and the command changes a colour property that the button also binds to.  Alternatively, if it's supposed to reflect 3 states, using a toggle button with the three state option is probably your better bet, as then you can set triggers against the IsChecked property of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the brush color in your click event:

`private void btnYourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnYourButton.BorderBrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00395c");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

By giving the borders a name and then they are accessible in the Trigger Property

```
<Button Width="64" Height="64" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Source="Images\Home_Icon_2.png" Width="54" Height="54"></Image>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                                <Border x:Name="button" CornerRadius="6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="64">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border x:Name="border1" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" BorderBrush="#0070b8" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=CornerRadius}">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="1" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="border2" BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="#e3e3e3" Opacity="0.5" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=CornerRadius}">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="1" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TextBlock.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="#e3e3e3" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00395c" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="border2" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#727272" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#c6c3c6" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```